Prove $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac1{n2^m+1}=1$
The First: I'm not sure if this identity has been asked before. I want to prove the summation:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac1{n2^m+1}=1$$
which I checked by mathematica, and was suggested 'not a difficult' result.
I simply write this to be
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac1{n2^m+1} & = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1} \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac1{n}-\frac1{n+2^{-m}}\right) \\
& = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1}\left(\frac1{n}-\frac1{n+2^{-m}}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\left(\frac1{n}-\frac1{n+2^{-m}}\right)$ reminds me the digamma function, yet I only have very few insight about its alternative analogous (something about Lerch function?)
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1}\left(\frac1{n}-\frac1{n+a}\right)
$$
Apparently, I am just on the wrong path.
The Second: A further question for curiosity, the alternative sum of the original one gives a Harmonic numbers' sum, namely
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac1{n2^m+1} = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} H_{2^{-m}} \simeq 2.35183...
$$
I wonder this one have a closed form result, or a special function representation, at least we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} H_{2^{-m}} 
& = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1}\zeta(n+1)\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}2^{-mn} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}\zeta(n+1)}{1-2^{-n}} \\
& = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1}\zeta(n+1) + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}\zeta(n+1)}{2^{n}-1} = 1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}\zeta(n+1)}{2^{n}-1}
\end{aligned}
$$
where even we already knew a similar decent result
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}\zeta(n+1)}{2^{n}} = 2(1-\ln2)
$$
where
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}\zeta(n+1)}{2^{n}-1}
$$
seems impossible to simplify.

The first one is Putnam 2016 B6. You can find solutions on sites like Art Of Problem Solving

@EfeGürel Nice! Thanks for reminding me the Putnam, I just kinda have a impression have seen this in some tests or forums.

MSE's dupe of the first question

... and a similar one.

Too long for a comment, but maybe a start of a proof, or a motivation. All of this works for $|x|<1,$ but we evaluate at $x=1$ at the end, so it is highly suspect.
If we write $f(x)=\log(1+x)=\sum_n(-1)^{n+1}\frac{x^n}n.$
Then for fixed $m,$ the the anti-derivative of $f(x^{2^m})$ is:
$$F_m(x)=\sum_n (-1)^{n+1}\frac{x^{2^mn+1}}{n(2^mn+1)}$$
But then if we define $$F(x)=\sum_m F_m(x),$$
we might expect to have the property that:
$$F'(x)=\sum_m\log(1+x^{2^m})= \log\prod_m (1+x^{2^m})$$
But that product is easily seen to be equal to $\frac1{1-x}=\sum_j x^j,$ because each $j$ can be written in exactly one way in binary.
So you get $F'(x)=\log\frac1{1-x}=\sum_j\frac{x^j}{j}.$
This gives that $F(1)=\sum_j\frac1{j(j+1)}=1.$
But $F(1)$ can be seen as your sum.
Missing details is whether anything here converges absolutely. They clearly don't in many cases. Clearly, $F'$ is not defined at $x=1,$ for example. Filling out these details might be a pain.
But in terms of formal power series, this sum works.
The problem is evaluating the functions on the boundaries of convergence radius.
